# SASS-LOADER Version 8.0.0 and up

Tags: laravel, sass-loader

Why i have errors white running "npm run dev" with 
SASS-LOader Ver. 8.0.0 and up and with Ver. 7.3.1 everything is ok ?

This happend when ive upgraded from laravel 6 to laravel 7.4

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (/Users/.../.../.../node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/Users/.../.../.../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:36:28)
    at /Users/.../.../.../node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /Users/.../.../.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/.../.../.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (/Users/.../.../.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/.../.../.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at /Users/.../.../.../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at /Users/borjanmukaetov/dona/Genomiks/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using laravel-mix since that's the default asset pipeline tool that is recommended in their [asset compiling documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix).

There was some compability issue with laravel-mix and sass-loader 8.0.0 as per this [issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2206). The issue is resolved in laravel-mix 5.0.0 so you can try updating laravel-mix.